# Can no longer push to BitBucket

Tags: xcode, bitbucket

I'm trying to push my code to BitBucket but Xcode keeps giving me the error:

```
SecureTransport error: I/O error (bummers) (-1)
```

If I try pushing using the command line, it keeps giving me the following error:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9820
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It was working but has suddenly stopped and I have no idea why. Googling hasn't brought up any answers either, although a solution to a similar error suggested to make sure php uses openssl. That didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am having the same issue. When I push my code there is some activity going on and after some time I get this error.

Comment: @AdnanAsghar I found the solution. You have to connect using SSH instead of HTTPS. In my case it happened because I was transferring too much in one go. Hope that helps!

Comment: I dont think thats the case because it was already working with HTTPS and also the code is pulled with no issues. Maybe its due to OSX upgrade which i performed a couple of days ago.

Comment: After a long processing the code is pushed. I haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting BitBucket, they suggested to connect using SSH rather than HTTPS. My problem was that I was transferring too much in one go. After I did that it worked!

Comment: how did you connect using SSH? did you push by Xcode or console?

Comment: anyway, from console I executed 2 commands to solve the issue that I had with Xcode. The first is `git branch NEW_BRANCH_NAME` and then `git push origin NEW_BRANCH_NAME`, and it worked. Maybe the problem was the size of the push indeed

Comment: @ddb I use SourceTree to handle my source control with bitbucket. Just changed the repository settings there.

Answer (score 2):

That problem was annoying me for a while and based on the accepted answer the detailed following scenario worked with me, Add ssh key to Bitbucket account

1. in Bitbucket site click your avatar
2. bitbucket settings
3. ssk keys
4. Copy your key to your clipboard with: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy` then past the key and give it any name
5. when **stupid** xcode shows that **stupid error dialog** point it to use ssh.

Thank you very much @Tometoyou !